# Python programming in the pocket C.H.I.P

Tags: python

I know that python is installed on the pocket C.H.I.P by default but I'm not  only want to write code in the terminal, I want to have an editor, I can simply use `nano code.py` but I want to have a better editor and to be able to see older programs.
Is it possible to use `sudo apt-get install thonny` then to run it use `thonny`?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `thonny` through `apt` , to run it use `thonny`. see 
[Installing via the distribution's package manager](https://github.com/thonny/thonny/wiki/Linux).

Also you can install `thonny` using `pip` (`pip3`):

Install the dependency `python3-tk` then:

```
pip install thonny
PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/.local/bin
thonny
```

add `PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/.local/bin` to your `.bashrc`:

```
echo "PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/.local/bin" >>  ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This looks just like installing thonny on every linux, does it work on C.H.I.P too?